# Xcode 5: Multiple test targets in one scheme: "Simulator already in use"

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, ios-simulator, xcode5

In Xcode 5, I have a workspace with multiple projects and a scheme that should run all the test targets of the various projects. When I kick off the tests about 3 test project targets pass. So far, so good. But at the fourth test target I get an error message from Xcode telling me that the simulator can't be launched because it is already in use.

Is there any way to kill the simulator between each test target(!) in a single(!) scheme?
Or are there other solutions?

**Edit:** I have opened a rdar for this: http://openradar.appspot.com/15153136

Thanks!

Comment: I've had this happen to me with a single test target in Xcode 5. Could not get it to start working again unless I restarted. Haven't found a way to fix it yet.

Comment: I might recommend going into the activity monitor through your system preferences and killing the ios simulator and xcode, that way you don't have to totally restart the computer.

Comment: Where you ever able to get a good solution for this? (For running units units inside Xcode 5)

Comment: @SanjitSaluja No, not yet unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

I have come into this error whenever i try to run my functional tests using calabash. One way to do this maybe be to run a script in the after each build process to kill the simulator.

this guy has wrote a bash script that does this
http://cdrussell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/script-to-kill-iphone-simulator-if.html

Might be worth running this as a build phase for each test target

Comment: Thank you, that's a great idea. The only problem is this: It will only run once! When I run multiple test targets, it first builds all of them and then tries to run all of them. So having a script run during the build process is too early. I could not figure out a way to run a script between test runs :(

Comment: Ahh i see, you could maybe try to implement a rake file and use xcodeBuild commandline to perform a clean all before each test target is run. ipa build --clean --archive --scheme appTarget --configuration Release --destination destination/archive